# z-index not working css pseudo before, after

Tags: z-index, css, pseudo-element

I am trying to achieve css3 curved shadow effect in one of the div something like **[this](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_box_shadow/)**. However, I ran into z-index problem. Even-though I set parent as position relative and set higher z-index it is still not working. Pseudo elements shows up on top of element. Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7mMaT/)** that demonstrates my problem also the code below. Any help will be much appreciated.

HTML

```
<div class="app-home-body-banners">
    <div>
        <ul style="height: 100px">
        </ul>
        <br class="clear" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.app-home-body-banners
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9; 
}
.app-home-body-banners:before, .app-home-body-banners:after
{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}

.app-home-body-banners:before
{
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:10px;
    right:10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    box-shadow:0 0 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    -moz-border-radius:100px / 10px;
    border-radius:100px / 10px;
}

.clear
{
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1px;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understood the question, what you are trying to achieve by using `content` and `z-index`?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something like this http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/css_box_shadow/

Comment: Why don't you look at the source? http://jsfiddle.net/TfusQ/

Answer (score 2):

remove the z-index from .app-home-body-banners: http://jsfiddle.net/7mMaT/9/

```
.app-home-body-banners {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    background-color: #E9E9E9; 
}
```